# Auto update a list of cells in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently trying to make an update sheet for some excel data at work. The purpose being so that the person that has to update the data every month need only update a single page and the data carries over to the rest of the sheet.

One the things that needs to update is a list of numbers that changes every month (example shown below). Is there an IF statement format or a macro that can be written so that when a number is typed in the yellow box, that number is moved to the most recent date, and the next two most recent ones are moved up the list so that only the data for the past three months is displayed.

I think I may be on to something with an IF statement I have on the side that reads

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C7),C7,C5)
```

It checks if there is a number in the yellow box and if so, to update the cell with that number and if not, to keep it the current number for that date.

I hope I'm on the right path with that, but if not, then any help given would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

UPDATE:

I've gotten this little bit of code typed in so that anytime data is entered into cell C7 the data in Cells C4 and C5 is shifted up one.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim x As Long, y As Long

```
Set sh = ActiveSheet

If Target = Range("C7") Then

    For y = 3 To 5

        For x = 3 To 3
            sh.Cells(y, x) = sh.Cells(y + 1, x)
        Next x
    Next y

End If
```

End Sub

What I'm having trouble figuring out now is how to write the data from C7 into C5 AFTER the cells have been shifted. Everything I've tried so far keeps crashing Excel. I'm assuming that is because it's looping without end, but I'm not sure how to fix that as I am very new to VBA in Excel.

Comment: So, from where data are coming. Which data have on source sheet

Comment: The main data is on the update sheet. From there, the necessary data will be copied to the appropriate sheets in the workbook. The formula itself can be anywhere on the update sheet since the necessary data will be copied over.

Comment: To further clarify, the current process has the employee updating each sheet in the workbook manually each month. the goal is to have a master sheet so that the employee can fill out that one sheet and the data in that sheet is copied over to the rest of the workbook.

One of the things they have to do is manually adjust the numbers beside the date setting so that only the three most recent dates are shown. the plan is to have them only have to enter the current months data in the yellow box, and the list will update rest itself.